# Streams collect(Supplier<R> supplier, BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator, BiConsumer<R,R> combiner) question

Tags: java

I'm looking at Streams:

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
              BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator,
              BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)
```

I see the example:

```
 List<String> asList = stringStream.collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add,
                                            ArrayList::addAll);
```

Why would I use this over?

```
 ArrayList<String> asList =     
     stringStream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<String>::new));
```

are they not doing the same thing?

The second example in the docs:

```
 String concat = stringStream.collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append,
                                      StringBuilder::append)
                             .toString();
```

I understand each individual String is passed to the accumulator, but what is passed to the last argument the combiner?

I'm expecting the combined to be `BiConsumer<R,R> c` which means `append(x, x)` should be called, where `x = new StringBuilder` but I don't see a method for accepting these two same types in the docs.

Comment: The combiner is only used for parallel streams.  And yes, those do the same thing.

Comment: @LouisWasserman any idea on the second example?

Comment: I answered the second question: nothing is; it's only used for parallel streams.  Or are you asking what `StringBuilder::append` does?  That's just a call to [StringBuilder.append(CharSequence)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Comment: If you look at the [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html) interface, you'll see it's essentially an encapsulation of the supplier, accumulator, and combiner. Though a `Collector` also has a "finisher", and also can report characteristics, which may help the stream implementation optimize the collection operation.

Comment: And note the second `StringBuilder::append` as the combiner would, as a lambda expression, look like `(firstAppender, secondAppender) -> firstAppender.append(secondAppender)`.

Comment: @notaorb Note that the `Stream#collect` is overloaded. One uses three parameters the other just one. Based upon your requirement you can use any of these. Also, sometimes the `reduce` method can be used to get the same result. And, your string concatenation can also be performed using the `stringStream.collect(Collectors.joining());`

Comment: For further clarification see this in Java documentation: [java.util.stream -> Reduction Operations (sub topic)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Comment: Don’t ask multiple, entirely different questions. The answer to the first question is: it is just an example. The answer to the second is, the logic for implementing a `BiConsumer` with a single argument method is the same for second parameter and the third parameter. If you understood, how it works for the second parameter or how `ArrayList::addAll` can act as a combiner, there should be no problem in understanding how a single argument `append` method can be used as a combiner. It’s exactly the same logic.